# Screenshots taken in ubuntu 14.04 LTS are not opening in windows 7

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7, screenshot

I have dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Screenshots taken in Ubuntu with default screenshot app do not work inside windows 7. I can't even open them with paint,windows photo viewer, PHOTOS, photoshop or with any other software. when i try to open it show error and when i try to rename again it shows error. but those screenshots successfully open in Ubuntu.

[NOT OPENING IN WINDOWS 7](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1944642fa36d913b!78053&authkey=!AA5JBkxzmzDj0nA&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cpng)

[When i try to rename the image, again shows error](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1944642fa36d913b!78053&authkey=!AA5JBkxzmzDj0nA&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cpng)

Comment: Link for first image http://1drv.ms/1JW7E4c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows can't handle any of these characters in file names, so you can't open or rename those files in Windows: `\/:*?"<>|`. Boot into Ubuntu and change the names before opening them in Windows.

Comment: Actually, Windows itself can handle file names with colons, but few applications can.

Comment: @DavidFoerster It can see them, but it can't interact with them. Try naming a file/folder to contain a colon, slash or asterisk. It won't work.

Comment: I'm not saying, the Windows Explorer *permits* colons (for backwards compatibility), just that the kernel and file system driver can *handle* colons (for POSIX compliance).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Got it.